# How to control the current while using "DC-DC XL6009 Adjustable Boost Step-up Power Converter Module Replace LM2577" in a circuit?

Tags: electronics

I want to power my WiFi modem with my powerbank and the modem's requirements is DC 12V-1A. But my Powerbank has DC 5V-2A that is why I will use a step up converter but how about the Amperes, how can I decrease it to 1A?

We have a terrible electric company and I want to make this so I can still use the internet while there is a power interruption and it takes 6 to 12 hours. Online classes are going on that is why I want to make this.

[DC-DC XL6009 Adjustable Boost Step-up Power Converter Module Replace LM2577]
specs: https://shopee.ph/product/201062777/6508449595

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So you want the power to the modem ie

```
12V * 1A = 12W
```

Then if you divide the power needed by the modem by the 5V of the powerbank you get:

```
12W / 5V = 2.4A
```

Now figure that the converter will also use / loose some power so you need a powerbank that supplies a minimum of 3A.

Which means that the powerbank you have is not large enough.

Comment: Can I do something about the default current of the power back to reach the needed ampere or do I really need to have a powerbank that is large enough to support it, or make a battery pack?

Comment: 2 powerbanks in parallel or how about 1 car battery and a solar panel & controller?

Comment: 2 powerbanks in parallel? let me try that

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlEnEn7ptmc&t=680s                                                 This guy caught my attention but I do not know what other kind of 18650 will I use

Comment: @Kyle why do I need to watch a video?

Comment: Maybe you got some ideas but I'm all good. Thanks

Comment: What is I use 12V 6Ah/10Hr battery straight to the modem?the modem needs 12V-1A as said